# Laravel select count in select

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I use laravel 4.2,
I'have a table called pois who contain some poi (poi = point of interest), i'have a second table called stamps who contain user stamps.

So i want to have the 3 pois where user have the maximum amount of stamp.
My problem is i dont know how to this using laravel queries.
I got my result using sql request, but it'snt the good way to do this.
here my sql request :

```
$pois = DB::select("SELECT *, (SELECT count(*) from stamps WHERE pois.id = stamps.poi_id) nbr_stamps FROM pois order by nbr_stamps DESC limit 3");
```

can you tell me how to do this with laravel queries ?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `selectRaw()` instead of `select()` and separate other parts of query to related methods:

```
$pois = DB::select(DB:raw("*, (SELECT count(*) from stamps WHERE pois.id = stamps.poi_id) nbr_stamps"))
    ->from('pois')
    ->orderBy('nbr_stamps', 'DESC')
    ->limit(3);
```

Read the [Query Builder documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/master/queries).

Comment: Quick reply , Good one !

Comment: thanks, but i got the following error :
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection' does not have a method 'selectRaw'

Comment: @Barzull `DB` should be `Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB`. Add `use DB` to the top of the file and try again.

Comment: i try with :
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB as DB at the top of my controller;

but nothing change ;(

Comment: paste here the result of this: `var_dump(get_class(new DB))`

Comment: here the result sir : 
string(29) "Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB"
i'm using laravel 4.2 for your informations

Comment: @Barzull strange :) Try using `DB::select(DB::raw())` instead of `DB::selectRaw()` - see updated answer

Comment: with : 
$pois = DB::select(DB::raw("*, (SELECT count(*) from stamps WHERE pois.id = stamps.poi_id) nbr_stamps"))
     ->from('pois')
     ->orderBy('nbr_stamps', 'DESC')
     ->limit(3);

i got : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*, (SELECT count(*) from stamps ....

Comment: @Barzull you've forgot `*` here: `DB::raw("*,`

Comment: stackoverflow remove the    " * " but it is ;)

Answer (score 2):

@thanks to limonte for the documentation link, i found the right way to write to select raw, here the solutions :

```
$pois = DB::table('pois')
        ->select(DB::raw("*, (SELECT count(*) from stamps WHERE pois.id = stamps.poi_id) nbr_stamps"))
        ->orderBy('nbr_stamps', 'DESC')
        ->take(3)
        ->get();
```

have a nice day ;)